# How to call a variable from addEventListener set in a JS class?

Tags: javascript, class

I am learning to use class in Javascript and I know how to call a variable defined in the constructor() from a method. My problem is that I am not able that same variable when the method itself is called by a listener.

I have tried to add this.value01.bind(this) unsuccessfully.

This is the code I'm using:

```
class mytest extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.value01 = document.body.clientWidth;

    this.testingMethod();

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.onWindowResize, false)
  }

  connectedCallback(){
    console.log( "From connectedCallback()", this.value01 ); // works
  }

  testingMethod(){
    console.log( "From testingMethod()", this.value01 );
  }

  onWindowResize(){
    console.log( "From onWindowResize()", this.value01 ); // undefined!
  }
}
customElements.define("my-test", mytest);
```

A fiddle is available at this url: https://jsfiddle.net/1mohk8jw/2/
Resize the window and check the console to see the problem.

I would like a way the reuse a variable defined in the constructor and used in a method called by a listener. How to get rid of the undefined from the onWindowResize() method using the constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing `undefined` because the binding to `this` is changing when the callback is invoked, it is pointing to the global object.

To solve it you need to do either of two things:

1. Bind `this` explicitly to your callback so that `this` is always referring to your class instance.
2. Use an arrow function syntax `() =>` which preserves the lexical `this`

```js
class Mytest{
  constructor(){
    this.value01 = document.body.clientWidth;
    window.addEventListener('click', this.thisTestWithoutBind, false);
    window.addEventListener('click', this.thisTestWithBind.bind(this), false);
    window.addEventListener('click', () => this.thisTestWithArrowFunc(), false);
  }

  thisTestWithoutBind(){
    console.log(Object.is(window, this)); //true
    console.log( "From thisTestWithoutBind()", this.value01 ); // undefined!
  }
  
  thisTestWithBind(){
    console.log( "From thisTestWithBind()", this.value01 ); // not undefined!
  }
    
  thisTestWithArrowFunc(){
    console.log( "From thisTestWithArrowFunc()", this.value01 ); // not undefined!
  }
}
new Mytest();
```

Comment: Ok, I understand the cause and the solution. Thank you every much!